# AAPT: error: resource android:drawable/ic_search is private

Tags: android, build.gradle, android-xml, android-drawable

I made a menu .xml file for an Action Bar in res/menu. Here's my code:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_search"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="Search">
    </item>
</menu>
```

When I try to run my app, I get this error:

> AAPT: error: resource android:drawable/ic_search is private.

I tried to clean the project, sync *Gradle*, etc., write `disable PrivateResource` in *Gradle*, write `tools:ignore="PrivateResource"` in my .xml. But none of this helps.

Thank you for helping me.

Comment: Copy the drawable to your project and use it, since the drawables and/or their names in SDK can change.

Comment: @TayyabMazhar It is in my project. My drawable in the folder _res/drawable_ and my menu in the _res/menu_.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found what I did wrong. I wrote

```
android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_search"
```

But it should be written like this:

```
android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
```